# deserialize json list from Rest server c#

Tags: c#, json, list, rest, json-deserialization

Just a little stuck here, I want to grab "notifications"(list) from the json that is sent back to me from the server. Please see below:

```
{"amountCashback": 0,"amountGratuity": 0, "amountTotal": 0, "notifications":["APPROVED" ],}
```

notifications being enum;

```
notifications {
string = ['APPROVED', 'BAD_SWIPE', 'CARD_ERROR', 'CARD_EXPIRED', 'CARD_NOT_SUPPORTED', 'CONNECTING', 'CONNECTION_MADE', 'DECLINED', 'DECLINED_BY_CARD', 'INSERT_CARD', 'PIN_ENTRY', 'PLEASE_WAIT', 'PRESENT_CARD', 'PRESENT_ONLY_ONE_CARD', 'PROCESSING_ERROR', 'REMOVE_CARD', 'RETRYING', 'REQUEST_SENT', 'RE_PRESENT_CARD', 'SIGNATURE_VERIFICATION', 'SIGNATURE_VERIFICATION_PROCESS_COMPLETED', 'SIGNATURE_VERIFICATION_PROCESS_COULD_NOT_BE_COMPLETED', 'SIGNATURE_VERIFICATION_IN_PROGRESS', 'SIGNATURE_VERIFICATION_TIMEOUT', 'TRANSACTION_FINISHED', 'TRANSACTION_STARTED']
```

Using json to c# I have created the class below

```
class Polling
{
    public int amountBase { get; set; }
    public int amountCashback { get; set; }
    public int amountGratuity { get; set; }
    public int amountTotal { get; set; }
    public string authCode { get; set; }
    public string cardSchemeName { get; set; }
    public string cardHolderVerificationMethod { get; set; }
    public string location { get; set; }
    public List<string> notifications { get; set; }
    public string paymentMethod { get; set; }
    public string transactionResult { get; set; }
    public DateTime transactionTime { get; set; }
    public string transactionType { get; set; }
    public string endPoint { get; set; }
    public httpVerb httpMethod { get; set; }
    public string userPassword { get; set; }
    public int sendAmount { get; set; }
    public string requestId { get; set; }}
```

I want to be able to deserialize and grab the notifications to display them on screen. Below I have added the code I am using for this.

```
 try
        {
            response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            using (Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
            {
                if (responseStream != null)
                {
                    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream))
                    {
                        strResponseValue = reader.ReadToEnd();
                    }
                    if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
                    {
                        dynamic jsonObjtpi = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(strResponseValue);
                        string notifications = jsonObjtpi.notifications.ToString();
                        return notifications;
                    }

                }
            }
        }
```

Thanks guys, really appreciate it

Comment: I'm not sure I see the question, what is the problem?

Comment: I believe the OP wants to grab `notifications[]` from the response. He's currently toString'ing them, which is useless based on his desire to render them.

Answer (score 0):

Json can use your strongly typed `Polling` object, e.g.

```
Polling polling = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Polling>(strResponseValue);
```

See https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeObject.htm